# Report level User permission in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to allow a user to view only a particular report in analytics dashboard.If yes then how ? I know user can be provided the read only access, bt i want to give the access permission at report level

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom report and emailing that out to the intended recipients (there is a repeat rule which can help you do that).

Comment: Yes I have considered this as last option. But as per the client , they don't want the emailing process. So somehow managed this by creating a view with traffic source filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not 100% sure, but I'd guess, it is not possible to apply such limitation.

First of all, [this support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495?hl=en) describes user rights, and nothing is mentioned or linked about further settings on top of detailed user levels.

In practice, I think it'd be quite hard to maintain such access levels, as most of the reports can have primary dimension changed, or combined with dozens of applicable secondary dimensions. This means, that narrowing access to a specific report still provides access to a wide range of metrics and dimensions.

Based on your business needs, you might consider creating additional views for example with subdomain filtering, traffic source filtering, customer location or technology, etc. This can introduce a limitation to relevant or restricted set of data, and permissions can be granted for specific views only.